# How to check if jQuery Tabs is initialized on an element before I can call its methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs, and I am trying to call the `destroy` method prior to running the tabs, but I am not sure how to check if it has been initialized first. I want to avoid an error stating that I can't call a method before initialize.

Here is my sample code:

```
// destroy first
$( '.tabs' ).tabs( 'destroy' ); // throws error if not initialized first

$( '.tabs' ).tabs();
```

I need to `destroy` first because these tabs are dynamically generated by the user (the user can add more tabs).  Once the tabs are added by the user, I need to run `tabs()` again, but I can't run it twice as it causes issues.  Therefore I need to destroy everything first and re-run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `refresh` (*you don't need to destroy and re-initialize the tabs*)

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

- http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-refresh

> Process any tabs that were added or removed directly in the DOM and
>   recompute the height of the tab panels

Comment: Thanks for this however I still need a way to check if it is initialized first because my application is quite complicated and has multiple levels of tabs.  Not just one so when I run "refresh", it will still give me the not initialized error.

Comment: I spent an hour with this issue of using ajax to rerender portions of page, which used jquery tabs and this answer right here is exactly what works.